# Determining if string contains date and time

Tags: c++

So, I am working on a project and I found several options, but it felt like none was actually fitting.

I have tracefiles with this format:

```
2018-08-09  09:30:34.118    Info    0   ...
2018-08-09  09:30:34.125    SystemInfo  0   ...
```

Different tracefiles should be compareable so date and time need to be cut out.

My program looks like this so far:

```
#include "targetver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void main(string filename)
{
ifstream in(filename);
ofstream out;
string line, sub_line;


if (in.is_open())
{
    out.open("stripped_" + filename);
    while (getline(in, line))
    {
        if (in.good())
        {
            if ()
            sub_line = line.substr(26);
            out << sub_line;

            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
    }
}

else
{
    cout << "File cannot be opened..." << endl;
}
}
```

I don't know how to check for this format and I would apreciate any kind of help or advice.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

Comment: [Hinnant's date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) can parse the millisecond-precision time point for you with `in >> parse("%F %T", tp)`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/parse C++20

Comment: why not just remove the first 28 characters of every line ? You don't even need to write your own code for that. On linux eg. : `cut -c29- logfile > logfile_stripped`

Comment: @SanderDeDycker maybe he wants to do it programmatically for some reason,

Comment: @Konrad : the OP already *is* doing just that. I'm just wondering why there's a need to do more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular expressions(regex) to find patterns in strings.
Here's how to use regex in C++:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string strs[] = { "2018-08-09 09:30:34.118", "Foo", "Hello" };
    regex reg(R"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3})");

    for (auto & i : strs)
    {
        smatch m;
        if (regex_search(i, m, reg))
            cout << "Correct!" << endl;
        else
            cout << "Not correct" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3})` means string format like `2018-08-09 09:30:34.118`. You can use `std::regex_search` to judge weather the string follows the format.